# Can't log in into Twitter for Android app after SSL Bypass

Tags: android, tls-intercept, certificate-pinning, twitter

I don't know if this is the right forum for this kind of question.

I was trying to intercept traffic from Twitter for Android app and for that I needed to bypass the SSL pin they implemented. Basically I was following [this tutorial](https://infosecwriteups.com/hail-frida-the-universal-ssl-pinning-bypass-for-android-e9e1d733d29)
and I got it to work.... sort of:

```
Spawned `com.twitter.android`. Resuming main thread!                    
[Android Emulator 5554::com.twitter.android]->
[.] Cert Pinning Bypass/Re-Pinning
[+] Loading our CA...
[o] Our CA Info: O=mitmproxy, CN=mitmproxy
[+] Creating a KeyStore for our CA...
[+] Creating a TrustManager that trusts the CA in our KeyStore...
[+] Our TrustManager is ready...
[+] Hijacking SSLContext methods now...
[-] Waiting for the app to invoke SSLContext.init()...
[o] App invoked javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.init...
[+] SSLContext initialized with our custom TrustManager!
[o] App invoked javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.init...
[+] SSLContext initialized with our custom TrustManager!
```

but now whenever I try to login I get a Toast saying
`You've exceeded the number of attempts. Please try again later`.
I also get `api_error_code=243` in mitmproxy saying that I should try again in an hour.
The issue is that I did this yesterday and when I tried today I still get the same error.
Does anybody know what might be the issue?

Comment: Looks like your connection to Twitter is being rate limited because you tried connecting to their API too many times. It might just be a temporary IP block in which case, you could just use a VPN until your IP is unblocked.

Comment: Have you tried it again without MITM? There might be a bot detection at Twitter and since the TLS fingerprint of Twitter via MITM looks different from the original fingerprint of the app it might be considered a bot.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich tried this and it didn't work, the same issue

Comment: @MarcWoodyard I don't really know how to connect my emulator to a VPN. I read that all I need to do is simply turn on VPN and restart emulator but that did nothing.
I managed to create new account while the script was running and I'm logged in and mitmproxy is getting all the traffic so I guess that is a workaround but not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it turns out everything worked fine I just got IP blocked. Turned on a VPN and there are no issues.